# Bug in knockout-3.4.0.debug.js?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

The code in [this jsbin](https://jsbin.com/sehibihoka/edit?html,css,js,output) seems to work correctly when Knockout is pointing to the non-debug version at ...knockout-3.4.0.js, but the debug version at ...knockout-3.4.0.debug.js has binding errors.

To reproduce, add a decimal such as 44.11111 to one of the textboxes. Correctly rounds to 2 decimal places. Add more decimals to make the number 44.11111 again. After the first update the precision does not update to 2 decimal places, ie: the extender has not fired and the number remains 44.11111.

Is there a bug in this version? Possibly with the minification?

https://jsbin.com/sehibihoka/edit?html,css,js,output

```js
ko.extenders.newnumeric = function(target, precision) {
  //create a writable computed observable to intercept writes to our observable
  var result = ko.pureComputed({
    read: target, //always return the original observables value
    write: function(newValue) {
      var current = target(),
        roundingMultiplier = Math.pow(10, precision),
        newValueAsNum = isNaN(newValue) ? 0 : parseFloat(+newValue),
        valueToWrite = Math.round(newValueAsNum * roundingMultiplier) / roundingMultiplier;

      //only write if it changed
      if (valueToWrite !== current) {
        target(valueToWrite);
      } else {
        //if the rounded value is the same, but a different value was written, force a notification for the current field
        if (newValue !== current) {
          target.notifySubscribers(valueToWrite);
        }
      }
    }
  }).extend({
    notify: 'always'
  });

  //initialize with current value to make sure it is rounded appropriately
  result(target());

  //return the new computed observable
  return result;
};



var data = {
  groups: [{
    id: 1,
    groupSelected: true,
    numbers: [{
      num: 33.00
    }, {
      num: 44.11
    }, {
      num: 2.5
    }, {
      num: 11.5
    }]
  }, {
    id: 2,
    groupSelected: true,
    numbers: [{
      num: 22
    }, {
      num: 2
    }]
  }, {
    id: 3,
    groupSelected: false,
    numbers: [{
      num: 1.25
    }, {
      num: 66.66
    }]
  }]
};

var mapping = {
  'groups': {
    create: function(options) {
      return new groupModel(options.data);
    }
  }
};

var numberMapping = {
  'numbers': {
    create: function(options) {
      return new numberModel(options.data);
    }
  }
};

var groupModel = function(data) {
  var self = this;
  ko.mapping.fromJS(data, numberMapping, self);
  self.GroupTotal = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    var sum = 0;
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.numbers(), function(r) {
      sum += (+r.num());
    });
    return sum.toFixed(2);
  });
};

var numberModel = function(data) {
  var self = this;
  ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);
  self.num = self.num.extend({
    newnumeric: 2
  });
};

var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping);

viewModel.GrandTotal = ko.pureComputed(function() {
  var sum = 0;
  // + is unary plus operator. alternate version is parseInt()
  ko.utils.arrayForEach(viewModel.groups(), function(r) {
    sum += (+r.GroupTotal());
  });
  return sum.toFixed(2);
});

// console.log(ko.mapping.toJS(viewModel));
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```css
   .divBlock {
     padding: 5px;
     background-color: #ccc;
   }
   .spanBlock {
     padding: 5px;
     margin: 5px;
     background-color: white;
   }
   .inputText {
     margin: 5px;
     width: 50px;
   }
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.js" integrity="sha256-1XMpEtA4eKXNNpXcJ1pmMPs8JV+nwLdEqwiJeCQEkyc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/knockout/knockout-3.4.0.debug.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout.mapping/2.4.1/knockout.mapping.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="divBlock" data-bind="foreach:groups">
    <div class="spanBlock">
      <div>
        <span data-bind="text: 'Id: ' + id() "></span>
      </div>
      <div data-bind="text: 'Group Total: ' + GroupTotal()"></div>
      <p data-bind="foreach:numbers">
        <input type="text" data-bind="value: num" class="inputText" />
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div data-bind="text: GrandTotal"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: it looks to me like it's an issue with the logic of your script.  You aren't writing the values out if they are "the same", but changing the value by such a small amount (e.g. 0.00111111) doesn't make the calculated total change.  If you later go back and change the value by a larger factor (e.g. 0.0111111111) the resulting calculation is enough for there to be a change, and an update to all the fields.

Comment: it seems to work correctly if you use the non-debug knockout and the sample is very similar to extender on the knockoutjs site

Comment: You should include your [mcve] **in the question itself**, using the jsbin as a reference only, so that the question is self-contained.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to show in your snippets. Didn't get any binding errors on the debug version as you said.  Side note: `parseFloat(+newValue)` doesn't look right. Don't you want to parse the value using `parseFloat()`? That `+` effectively bypasses that.

Comment: Updated the instructions to make them a little more clear. The extender fires the first time then does not, so be sure to put the number in a second time, leaving any new changes with extra digits like 44.11111. The extender code above is almost identical to the code on the knockoutjs.com "Using Extenders" page.  My original code worked a little differently. My intent here is confirm whether there is a bug, probably in the minification.

Comment: There's a *lot* of code in the question. It would be a lot easier to spot the problem and help with the root cause analysis if you could trim it down to only the necessary bits.